# Generating selector lists in LESS

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

Live demo here: http://codepen.io/KenPowers/pen/Ddfqh

Consider the following LESS code:

```
// Hide all list items by default and make internal labels have pointer cursors
li {
  display: none;
  label {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}

// This function generates selectors and corresponding css
.gen (@tag) {
  @sel: ~"#@{tag}:checked";
  @{sel} {
    & ~ ul > li[data-index~=@{tag}] {
      display: list-item;
    }
    & ~ ul > li > label[for=@{tag}] {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}

// Generate required selectors and css
.gen("foo");
.gen("bar");
.gen("baz");
```

It generates the following CSS:

```
li {
  display: none;
}
li label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#foo:checked ~ ul > li[data-index~="foo"] {
  display: list-item;
}
#foo:checked ~ ul > li > label[for="foo"] {
  color: red;
}
#bar:checked ~ ul > li[data-index~="bar"] {
  display: list-item;
}
#bar:checked ~ ul > li > label[for="bar"] {
  color: red;
}
#baz:checked ~ ul > li[data-index~="baz"] {
  display: list-item;
}
#baz:checked ~ ul > li > label[for="baz"] {
  color: red;
}
```

However, a more compressed output may look like the following:

```
li {
  display: none;
}
li label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#foo:checked ~ ul > li[data-index~="foo"],
#bar:checked ~ ul > li[data-index~="bar"],
#baz:checked ~ ul > li[data-index~="baz"] {
  display: list-item;
}
#foo:checked ~ ul > li > label[for="foo"],
#bar:checked ~ ul > li > label[for="bar"],
#baz:checked ~ ul > li > label[for="baz"] {
  color: red;
}
```

Is there a way I can modify the original LESS to generate the second CSS listing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Less 1.4.0+ you can [`:extend`](http://lesscss.org/#-extend) a placeholder class:

```
.dp-list-item {
  display: list-item;
}
.label-color {
  color: red;
}

// This function generates selectors and corresponding css
.gen (@tag) {
  @sel: ~"#@{tag}:checked ~ ul > li";
  @{sel} {
    &[data-index~=@{tag}]:extend(.dp-list-item){}
    & > label[for=@{tag}]:extend(.label-color){}
  }
}

// Generate required selectors and css
.gen("foo");
.gen("bar");
.gen("baz");
```

[**Forked pen**](http://codepen.io/UltCombo/pen/lwmnc)

Generated CSS:

```
.dp-list-item,
#foo:checked ~ ul > li[data-index~="foo"],
#bar:checked ~ ul > li[data-index~="bar"],
#baz:checked ~ ul > li[data-index~="baz"] {
  display: list-item;
}
.label-color,
#foo:checked ~ ul > li > label[for="foo"],
#bar:checked ~ ul > li > label[for="bar"],
#baz:checked ~ ul > li > label[for="baz"] {
  color: red;
}
```

As you can see, the only drawback is that both classes which I've used as placeholders will be in the generated CSS. I believe this can't be worked around until Less implements something akin to Sass' [placeholder selectors](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholder_selectors_).

ps. I've omitted the global `li` rules which are not part of the mixin for brevity.

---

As per OP request, here is a Sass (with `.scss` syntax) equivalent:

```
//placeholder selectors
%dp-list-item {
  display: list-item;
}
%label-color {
  color: red;
}

// This function generates selectors and corresponding css
@mixin gen($tag) {
  ##{$tag}:checked ~ ul > li {
    &[data-index~=#{$tag}] {
      @extend %dp-list-item;
    }
    & > label[for=#{$tag}] {
      @extend %label-color;
    }
  }
}

// Generate required selectors and css
@each $item in (foo bar baz) {
  @include gen($item);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/UltCombo/pen/xDmbq)

Generated CSS:

```
#foo:checked ~ ul > li[data-index~=foo], #bar:checked ~ ul > li[data-index~=bar], #baz:checked ~ ul > li[data-index~=baz] {
  display: list-item;
}

#foo:checked ~ ul > li > label[for=foo], #bar:checked ~ ul > li > label[for=bar], #baz:checked ~ ul > li > label[for=baz] {
  color: red;
}
```

You can see that Sass' syntax is rather verbose when compared to Less. Sass also has some nice features such as [control directives](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#control_directives) and excellent [interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) which I've applied in the example above.

Comment: Assuming I wanted to use SASS, would you be willing to supply the equivalent code utilizing placeholder selectors?

Comment: @KPthunder Sure thing, added a Sass example. `=]`