# multiple nested selectors with variables in Less

Tags: css, variables, css-selectors, less

I want to build some CSS along these lines:

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {some rule}
h1 a,h2 a,h3 a,h4 a,h5 a,h6 a {color: inherit;}
h1 span,h2 span,h3 span,h4 span,h5 span,h6 span {another rule;}
```

It would be useful if I could create a variable like this:

```
@headings: h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6;
```

and then maybe do something like this:

```
@{headings} {
  & a {color: inherit;}
}
```

Unfortunately this gives me:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 a {
  color: inherit;
}
```

Is what I want possible? This is a simple version of what I want to do but I would also find useful for working with HTML input types and other instances of multiple selectors that often appear together.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23954580/2712740 solution #3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Build list of selectors with LESS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935102/build-list-of-selectors-with-less)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that appears to be the inverse of my problem and gives me

    h1 a , h1 span  {rule}

instead of 

    h1 a,h2 a,h3 a,h4 a,h5 a,h6 a {rule}
    h1 span,h2 a,h3 a,h4 a,h5 a,h6 a {another rule;}

Comment: Well, it's actually exactly the same code that can give you what you need (it may just look too cryptic to understand how to use it correctly though). Also speaking of `h1 span, h2 a, h3 a ...` - I assume it's a typo since there'no way `@{headings} {...}` can give such output (even if it would work that way).. I.e. for `h1 span, h2 a, h3 a ...` you have to have `h1` and `h2, h3, ...` separated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**#1**
Just yet one more solution in addition to @helderdarocha's answer and those given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/23954580/2712740. Maybe be this one could look a bit more clear:

```
// define header list as usual just
// put a mixin call with some predefined name there
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {.headings}

// now to add styles/childs to the header list just add the mixin definitions:

.headings() {
    some: rule;
}

.headings() {
  a {color: inherit}
}

.headings() {
  span {another: rule}
}

// etc.
```

The limitation of this solution is that `h1, h2, h3 ... {}` and `.headings` should be defined at the same level. Additionally, it's important to keep in mind that all these styles will output to CSS at the point of `h1, h2, h3 ... {}` definition not at the point of `.headings` definitions, so it may break your cascading overrides if you have some).

---

**#2**
The alt. solution I'm copy-pasting from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23954580/2712740 #3, basicaly it's the same as **#1** but w/o its limitations (just having more special scary symbols):

```
// the "variable":
.headings(@-) {
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
        {@-();}}


// usage:

.headings({
    some: rule;
});

.headings({
    a {color: inherit}
});

.headings({
    span {another: rule}
});

//etc.
```

Comment: Just in case I'm yet again assuming `h1 span,h2 a,h3 a,h4 a,h5 a,h6 a {another rule;}` is a typo (having it that way and than hardcoding `if (h1) {...} else {...}` for the `@headings` looks like a bloody overengineering if compared to plain CSS `h1 span {...}; h2, h3, ... {...}`.

Comment: You are correct it was a failure to copy and paste the span across to the other bits. I am wanting to use a simple method that I can use in a few places, this was a simple example but I think it will be useful in my forms code where I currently have to specify different input types like password and number in multiple places. I'll have a look at the solutions in the morning when my brain is a little more awake.

Comment: Thanks for the answers everyone. Seven-phases-max's first answer is the way I'll go. I'm a CSSer rather than a javascripter so this is much simpler for me to understand and the code needs to be passable to god knows whom in a few months and they may also not understand what is going on with more complicated stuff.

Answer (score 3):

### Use a Ruleset

If you define your heading group as a [ruleset](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature) with a mixin call to set properties with, then you can do this:

```
@headings: {h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {.setProps()}};


& {
    .setProps() {
        & {
            some: rule;
        }
        a {
            color: inherit;
        }
        span {
            another: rule;
        }
    }
    @headings();
}
```

I've isolated the whole thing inside `&` just so the `.setProps()` can be localized (it would work without it, but it would be setting the `.setProps()` globally. Also, the nested `& {}` bracketing is not necessary, but I find that it helps show what the "default" for the `@headings` is going to be.

This can be used sequentially, if desired, like so:

```
& {
    .setProps() {  some: rule; }
    @headings();
}
& {
    .setProps() { a {color: inherit;}}
    @headings();
}
& {
    .setProps() { span {another: rule;}}
    @headings();
}
```

Both will output like so:

```
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  some: rule;
}
h1 a,
h2 a,
h3 a,
h4 a,
h5 a,
h6 a {
  color: inherit;
}
h1 span,
h2 span,
h3 span,
h4 span,
h5 span,
h6 span {
  another: rule;
}
```

Comment: Sorry to spoil it but it seems that this way it's even more complicated then just with pure detached-rulesets (i.e. as in stackoverflow.com/a/23954580/2712740 solution #3). Normally you don't need "callback mixins" if you already decide to use detached-rulesets (just because the detached-ruleset can serve as callback itself) OK, I'll update my answer to not link to the old one again and again.

Comment: @seven-phases-max: Not really a spoiler, as I agree that your #3 in that solution is better (and less "complicated," though perhaps not as intuitively "obvious" what is happening). I offered this here only because it is yet a _different_ way of going about it. I tend to like to give as many options as possible and let users decide what they deem best for their situations.

Answer (score 1):

If you have these variables and selectors:

```
@headings: h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6;

@{headings} {
    some-rule: rule;    
}
.headings { // this is a placeholder
    color: inherit;
}
h1 span {
    other-rule: rule;
}
```

You can use this mixin to generate the code you want:

```
.mixin(@headings; @count) when (@count > 0) {
    .mixin(@headings; @count - 1);
    @heading: extract(@headings, @count);
    @{heading}{
        & a:extend(.headings) {}
        & a:extend(h1 span) when not (@heading = h1) {}
    }
}
```

Calling:

```
.mixin(@headings, length(@headings));
```

will generate:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  some-rule: rule;
}
.headings,
h1 a,
h2 a,
h3 a,
h4 a,
h5 a,
h6 a {
  color: inherit;
}
h1 span,
h2 a,
h3 a,
h4 a,
h5 a,
h6 a {
  other-rule: rule;
}
```

Comment: What absolutely baffles me is that `h1 .. h6 { a {} }` generates `h1 a .. h6 a` as one would expect, but `@headings: h1 .. h6; @{headings} { a {} }` does something entirely different. I wonder if it's just one of those mysterious quirks of LESS variable interpolation.

Comment: It's just because an interpolated variable always interpreted as a single selector element and this is because there's no way to know if it's not w/o reparsing variable's value from scratch at this point. The Less is one-pass compiler by design so each special case when you need to reparse something is the pain in the ass (requires a bunch of new code) (Historically it's a back-side of the lazy-loading).