# Add a value to a list in Less CSS

Tags: css, list, append, less, concatenation

Given the following:

```
@list: 'banana', 'apple';
```

How would you add the value 'orange' to this list in LESS CSS?

I have tried the following without success:

```
@list+: 'orange';
@list: @list + 'orange';
@list: @list ~ 'orange';
```

Comment: Based on a comment found [**here**](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1545), I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do that. Less variables use **the last declaration** wins rule. A variable referencing itself will create a loop, the assigned value becomes the last declared, and so on.

You can use a [loop](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature) to build a list which you can assign as a value to a property.

The [LESS loops used to generate column classes in twitter - How do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306437/less-loops-used-to-generate-column-classes-in-twitter-how-do-they-work/26653893) shows you how to build a list of selectors.

Answer (score 1):

This wasn't exactly your question, but you *can* create a new list that includes the original:

```less
@list: 'banana', 'apple';
@new-list: 'orange', @list;

// Using these in classes for display in less2dss.org:
.list {
  content: @list;
}
.new-list {
  content: @new-list;
}
```

This outputs this (meaningless) CSS as confirmation:

```css
.list {
  content: 'banana', 'apple';
}
.new-list {
  content: 'orange', 'banana', 'apple';
}
```

See this in [less2css](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40list%3A%20'banana'%2C%20'apple'%3B%5Cn%40new-list%3A%20'orange'%2C%20%40list%3B%5Cn%5Cn%2F%2F%20Using%20these%20in%20classes%20for%20display%20in%20less2css.org%3A%5Cn.list%20%7B%5Cn%20%20content%3A%20%40list%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn.new-list%20%7B%5Cn%20%20content%3A%20%40new-list%3B%5Cn%7D%22%7D).