# LESS variable self concatenation

Tags: javascript, css, less

This

```
.a {
  @a: 1;
  @b: 2;
  @concat: @a;
  @concat: ~"@{concat}@{b}";
  margin: @concat;
}
```

gives an error.

> Syntax error: too much recursion

However, this

```
.a {
  @a: 1;
  @b: 2;
  @concat: e(`(function (a, b) {
    var concat = "" + a;
    concat += b;
    return concat;
  })(@{a}, @{b})`);
  margin: @concat;
}
```

would work.

Is there a trick to concatenate a string with itself with LESS only (without `concat1`, `concat2`, etc variables)?

Note that the code above isn't a subject for simplification because it will use conditionals. The code has to generate

```
.optional-conditional-class1, .optional-conditional-class2, .optional-conditional-class3 {
....
}
```

in a [similar](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins/grid-framework.less#L6) loop fashion. That's why I want to form concatenated string with the list of classes.

Comment: Less is a declarative language so its variables can't be used to modify themselves. What task are you trying to solve (looks like [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))?

Comment: `if (aCondition) { concat += a }; if (bCondition) { concat += b };` That's simplified js pseudocode. It could be easily done with LESS, except... well, the recursion thing.

Comment: Sure, I updated the question. Hope it explains something.

Comment: For you edit see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306437 (don't miss my comments there). In short: (currently) the best way to generate a selector list in Less is the [`extend`](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature) feature and not some string-based manipulation. String-based selector generation is still possible (no self-concatenation is necessary actually) but not recommended due to many limitations (simply because selectors in Less are not strings therefor string-based selectors will break in many situations).

Comment: Either way, if you could show some more code (in particular what is initial variable and what are those conditions) I guess I could give some examples on how to generate selector ist via string-based-concatenation *w/o* variable-self-concatenation).

Comment: Thanks, you're very helpful, there are not so many LESS guys here. `extend` doesn't seem to fit well into that recursive loop that Bootstrap uses (and I'm not too fond of doing `when` for conditionals with each iteration). I guess I will revise the approach and come up with another question if anything.

Comment: >extend doesn't seem to fit well into that recursive loop that Bootstrap uses - see my last comment in that thread - I wrote a whole sort-of blog-post on how to rewrite that Bootstrap code using `extend`.

Comment: Yes, I'm checking your less.curious repo, it's great, thanks again for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, essentially, it is possible, though not on the same scope. I've ended up with recursive approach like this

```
    .concat-test {
      .concat(@rest...) {
        ._concat(@i, @result, @rest...) {
          @var: extract(@rest, @i);
          .-() when (@i > length(@rest)) {
            @concat: @result;
          }
          .-() when (default()) {
            ._concat(@i+1, ~"@{result}@{var}", @rest);
          }
          .-();
        }
        ._concat(1, "", @rest);
      }

      @a:a;
      @b:b;
      @c:c;

      .concat(@a, @b, @c, @b, @a);
      concat: @concat;
    }
```

Comment: Which is basically what [`less-plugin-lists:join`](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less-plugin-lists/blob/master/docs/ref.md#join) (see also `cat`) does in one line... ;)

Comment: @seven-phases-max Thanks! Too bad I had no chance to stumble on it when googling 'less css functions lib'. I will take a look at your other repos. I've already done it with `e(\`(function () { return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(", ") })(@{a}, @{b})\`)` but wanted to recreate it with LESS only.