# LessCss selector interpolation with parent reference

Tags: less

i have the problem, that i want to use all types of inputs like number, url, email ... so all which are styled as normal text... i use them very often in my file so i wanted to create a
`selector interpolation`  to manage this:

```
@inputs: ~"input[type=number],  input[type=url], input[type=email], input[type=date], input[type=password], input[type=text]";
```

this works fine until i want to put them into nesting...

so ..

```
#content {
    @{inputs} {width: 20%}  
}
```

will output:

```
#content input[type=number], input[type=url], ... {width: 20%}
```

but i need this:

```
#content input[type=number], #content input[type=url], ... {width: 20%}
```

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/24407388/2712740, http://stackoverflow.com/q/23935102/2712740.

Comment: their solution works well in th online compiler.. but not in my app.. may this be caused by the plugin i am using? Using Grails (Java ) `Less-Assets-Pipeline-1.10.0`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution finally :)
i changed the string interpolator:

```
@inputs: ~"input[type=number],  input[type=url], input[type=email], input[type=date], input[type=password], input[type=text]";
```

to:

```
@inputs: ~"input[type=number]," + " &" ~"input[type=url]," + " &" ~"input[type=email]," + " &" ~"input[type=date]," + " &" ~"input[type=password]," + " &" ~"input[type=text]";
```

## Update:

This solution only works in this compiler: [leafo.net/lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/editor.html#%40inputs%3A%20~%22input%5Btype%3Dnumber%5D%2C%22%20%2B%20%22%20%26%22%20~%22input%5Btype%3Durl%5D%2C%22%20%2B%20%22%20%26%22%20~%22input%5Btype%3Demail%5D%2C%22%20%2B%20%22%20%26%22%20~%22input%5Btype%3Ddate%5D%2C%22%20%2B%20%22%20%26%22%20~%22input%5Btype%3Dpassword%5D%2C%22%20%2B%20%22%20%26%22%20~%22input%5Btype%3Dtext%5D%22%3B%0Abody%7B%0A%40%7Binputs%7D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20width%3A%2020px%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Comment: Hmm, this is not going to work actually. What Less compiler do you test it with?

Comment: ya, i saw it... i used this online compiler, but in my app it doesnt work...: http://leafo.net/lessphp/editor.html#%40inputs%3A%20~%22input%5Btype%3Dnumber%5D%2C%22%20%2B%20%22%20%26%22%20~%22input%5Btype%3Durl%5D%2C%22%20%2B%20%22%20%26%22%20~%22input%5Btype%3Demail%5D%2C%22%20%2B%20%22%20%26%22%20~%22input%5Btype%3Ddate%5D%2C%22%20%2B%20%22%20%26%22%20~%22input%5Btype%3Dpassword%5D%2C%22%20%2B%20%22%20%26%22%20~%22input%5Btype%3Dtext%5D%22%3B%0Abody%7B%0A%40%7Binputs%7D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20width%3A%2020px%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D