# Is it possible to reference a parent selector in a LESS variable?

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to use the ampersand to bring parent selectors into a variable containing pseudo-class selectors:

```
.my-selector,
.my-other-selector {
  @{pseudo-states} {
    // rules
  }
}
```

The following attempts all produced the literal variable content in the generated css:

```
@pseudo-states: &:hover, &:focus, &:active, &.active;
@pseudo-states: ~"&:hover, &:focus, &:active, &.active";
@pseudo-states: ~"\&:hover, \&:focus, \&:active, \&.active;
```

Any way to achieve this?

It seems that LESS simply doesn't process the contents of variables, so this question may come down to whether or not there's a way to change that.

Comment: No, neither ampersand nor comma have any special meaning in the interpolated variable. For possible workarounds see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935102.

Comment: @ShawnErquhart Yes, the bounty will probably attract more attention and maybe you will get your answer. In the meantime, see if this [sample](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwGzpP) helps you any bit. I am not adding this as answer because it doesn't match your requirements 100% but will do so if you wish me to.

Comment: Thanks for the live example - that does work, but it's still non-normative. Really hoping to use a simple inline replacement for the selectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adopting one of examples linked in comments above, here's the most (so far) clean solution:

```cpp
// usage:

.my-selector,
.my-other-selector {
    .pseudo-states({
        /* rules */
    });
}

// impl.:

.pseudo-states(@-) {
    &:hover, &:focus, &:active, &.active {@-();}
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of using a mixin as an alternative, and it's what I'll apparently have to do, but it feels like overkill for drying up usage of a few common selectors. Posted the question hoping some genius out there had a better solution. Thanks for suggesting, though, upvote for that.

Comment: The usage part is just 1 char larger if compared to possible selector interpolation syntax ;)

Comment: It's not the length I have issue with, it's the divergence of syntax by enclosing the ruleset in parens + curlies. Would like to get closer to actual css, not further from it.

Comment: @ShawnErquhart: Unless we use some complex hack, what you are trying to achieve is almost impossible. I would suggest using the above approach instead of any other hacks because this is easier to interpret atleast for those who know the basics of Less.

Comment: @Harry well, necessity is the mother of invention. Sometimes a problem seems insurmountable until someone looks at it the right away. When I used Sass, I had a simple `@hover-states` var that worked like a charm. I don't like passing an entire ruleset as an arg for something so simple.

I'm adding a bounty on this, we'll see where it goes.

Comment: Had I realized @seven-phases-max was a less.js core contributor I may have foregone the bounty. This is indeed the only way (for now), but if you're interested in implementing the ideal functionality, check out: https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1421