# how to write less ruleset for assigning properties for multiple class names

Tags: css, less, less-mixins

I am trying to assign properties to multiple class names within one ruleset, where all of the properties assigned with in this ruleset will get appended to different class names.

```
.multipleClass(@className...;@rules){
    @clssName: ~'.@{className},.@{className}';
    @{clssName}{
    rules();
    }
}

 .multipleClass(class1,class2,class3;{
        padding:0.25em;
        font-size:1.5em;
        line-height:2.5em;
        });
```

Desired output:

```
    .class1,.class2,.class3{
        padding:0.25em;
        font-size:1.5em;
        line-height:2.5em;
```

}

I am getting Parse Error. Can it be done? 
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

@Harry I just thought not to complicate the matter so posted different wrapper.
and with &:extend I am unable to control it properly. As my stylesheet is a working one and I am rewriting the entire thing the give it a theme. In order to do that I need to organize colour related mixins and rest of the rulesets and mixins which deal with fontSizes, margins, paddings and widths. Its about 4000 lines of css code.

```
    .formater(@className...; @rules; @parent-append: false) {
        @clssName: ~'.@{className},.@{className}';
        & when not (@parent-append = false) {
        &.@{className} {
        @rules();
        }
        }
        & when (@parent-append = false) {
          .@{className} {
           @rules();
           }
       }  
     }
```

Comment: Sorry Friend my Desired output is not a parent child relationship, but an independent classes with common properties. I need a comma to separate these classes.

Comment: I feel you are complicating things a bit. Can we know why you need these wrapper classes which take selectors as one argument and rulesets as another? That'd help in providing a proper solution. I would recommend you to have a look at `:extend`. If you really want to stick to your current approach, pass the first argument as `~".class1, .class2"` and use the `.formater()` mixin from previous question itself.

Comment: .multipleClass() is just for explanation.

Comment: Ok, but still I feel this is way too complicated. You can pass the first argument as mentioned in my previous comment and it would form selector groups but I wouldn't really recommend it.

Comment: @Harry I tried that as a string, but got an issue ; for suppose I have a tag in this group and it only gets appended to the last className for example    .colourclass1, colourclass2 a{property:value}.

Comment: Those types of things are part of the reason why I said I wouldn't be recommending writing wrapper mixins like this. They'd lead to more trouble than they're worth. If you still insist, have a look at loops where you read every class name from the first string and then set their rules. I can provide you an answer but that'd be kind of guiding you the wrong way.

Comment: @Harry I will do as you have suggested and keep you informed about the same.

Comment: @Sergey Denisov  I added it because I cannot add code in comments and it will not be a formatted code and difficult to read. I have edited and added the same in  question post itself. I will not commit same mistake again.Thank you.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/23954580/2712740 (I also share Harry's concerns about sort of overengineered concept of your `.formatter` mixin mentioned in a few recent Qs... Maybe it has its reasons to be used, but then it would be useful to see a particular example of why exactly it's necessary (who knows maybe it's just an XY-problem)).