# Less: Combining selector variables

Tags: less

Given i want to simplify the following LESS code:

```
@title1: ~"h1.someclass > a";
@title2: ~"h1.otherclass > a";

@{title1},@{title2} {
  &:after {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

which evaluates to:

```
h1.someclass > a:after,
h1.otherclass > a:after {
  display: none;
}
```

I tried to merge the classes by using

```
@titles: ~"@{title1},@{title2}"; // Combine selectors for easier code
@{titles} {
  &:after {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

This however will yield different CSS.

```
h1.someclass > a,h1.otherclass > a:after {
  display: none;
}
```

Is this due to the Lazy Evaluation of the variables? If so, why does it yield the CSS this way? And is there a diffrent way of combining selector variables and later using &:after?

Comment: Is this due to the Lazy Evaluation of the variables? - No. This is because escaped strings (see [definition](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-escaping)) are not considered to be a complex selector (so commas or other special ops have no meaning there). For more references see [#2263](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2263). So some other approach is required (see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/23954580/271274 *part #3*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(almost copy-pasting from the more wide https://stackoverflow.com/a/23954580/271274)

There're two problems with your attempt:

1. By definition a content of [escaped strings](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-escaping) is not a subject for any kind of evaluation at all, so commas (as well as any other special ops) have no meaning there.
2. Variable interpolation in selectors assumes a single interpolated variable contains only a single selector element. So, strictly speaking, even `~"h1.someclass > a"` is already nothing but a hack expected to have side-effects and unspecified/undefined behaviour for anything but extremely trivial cases.

So in your code above the value of `@titles` works just as a simple/single selector element (the same as `body` for example).

I.e. in summary and in general, "string-based selector manipulation" (like `~"@{title1}, @{title2}"`) should be avoided where possible simply because in Less *selectors are not strings and strings are not selectors* (nor they automatically converted to each other except in, yet again, certain extremely trivial cases).

---

So far the only non-hackish method to define a reusable list of selectors in Less is a mixin (mixins can be considered as "variables" too even if they have another syntax) that puts an arbitrary set of rules into a ruleset having the said list as its selector. E.g. for your example above it would be something like:

```less
@title1: ~"h1.someclass  > a";
@title2: ~"h1.otherclass > a";

.titles(@rules) {
    @{title1}, @{title2} {@rules();}
}

// usage:

.titles({
    &:after {
        display: none;
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40title1%3A%20~%5C%22h1.someclass%20%20%3E%20a%5C%22%3B%5Cn%40title2%3A%20~%5C%22h1.otherclass%20%3E%20a%5C%22%3B%5Cn%5Cn.titles(%40rules)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40%7Btitle1%7D%2C%20%40%7Btitle2%7D%20%7B%40rules()%3B%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%2F%2F%20usage%3A%5Cn%5Cn.titles(%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%26%3Aafter%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20display%3A%20none%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D)%3B%22%7D).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. The idea with the mixin is nice, Still seems quite hacky, but better then having (in my case) 4 diffrent long selectors stacked up :).