# Create comma separated selectors with Less loop and interpolated extend

Tags: css, loops, less, extend

I'm trying to a nice localisation mixin that will give me the following output:

```
.gb .PARENT,
.ie .PARENT {
    color: red;
}
```

I've created a mixin that you pass through locations and the rules, like so:

```
.button {
  .localise(gb au ie, {
    color: red;
  })
}
```

In my mixin im hoping to loop through each location and output the rules - I'm creating a "throw away" class initially that i can extend from each of the locations so it'll give me the desired output - but thats what im coming up against.

It seems that you cannot use interpolation in the extends function so i'm unable to nicely get my parent element - ideally i would have:

```
.@{name} &:extend(INTERPOLATED-PARENT .localise all) {}
```

but i'm having to use:

```
.@{name} &:extend(.button .localise all) {}
```

Can anyone think of a way i'm able to pass through a variable parent class like the above "INTERPOLATED-PARENT" example?

Here's a codepen of where i'm at so far:

https://codepen.io/sonnyprince/pen/MoMOaq

Thanks!

Comment: `extend` does not support interpolated selectors. So what you need is to keep a fixed name ruleset that your "interpolated parent" extends too.

Comment: Yes I did read that from the LESS docs.
How would a fixed name ruleset work - would that not be _too_ generic for use of this mixin on multiple elements? Resulting in multiple classes having related styling, even when unrelated?

Comment: That's too broad. If you want just show an example with that "interpolated parent" you want and I'll show how to convert it to a working thing (in most cases this is done w/o loosing anything and the only disadvantage is that "dummy" fixed name never used in HTML).

Comment: ^ Though never mind, I guess I can understand what you actually want from your example so just give some time to think of it :) As the problem is not in really the interpolate selector but either the selector or styles you want to pass to a mixin - i.e. one `.localise` call shoud extend `.button`, another shoud extend `.knob`, yet another - another an so on, right?).

Comment: Btw., at quick glance, looking at your codepen example I now wonder if you need any `extend` there *at all*, wouldn't plain nesting result in [the same](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.localise%20%26%2C%5Cn.ie%2C%20.au%2C%20.gb%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20button%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3A%20red%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D)? Though if the localisation list itself is supposed to be a variable itself it gets a bit more complicated (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23954580/2712740 - method `#3`).

Comment: Exactly - One could extend `.button` another could extend `.table` - it should be totally flexible. And again you're right, the localisation list needs to be variable too - thats the added complication otherwise i would just hard coded the localisation list and rendered the @rules within there! :)

Comment: Then your problem is not really is that the extend does not support "interpolated parent" but in "extend can't extend 'passed-in' identifiers" (e.g. basically there you'd really need not supported `extend(@{parent});`). So I actually suggest a method used in the A linked above - e.g. something [like this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/defec6e9589c0b07addd91bb4fad04a9#file-45191971-less) (an alternative would be "string-based" methods illustrated in the same A - they may give a bit more clear usage in certain case but have dead issued when generated selectors are nested in any way).

Comment: Speaking of "interpolated parent" it coud be just a terminology blurring. Just for the reference see ["extend interpolated selectors"](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2200) vs. ["extend variables"](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1485) (the latter does look like an interpolation of course but it's usually not referred to as "interpolated selector").

Comment: Unfortunately that's straying too far away from what i'm looking for - The languages you pass through arent variable at the time of defining the mixin and i wouldn't be able to use this nesting within classes.

If the `&` worked in `extend` it would be perfect!