# Group several IDs into an impromptu “class”

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a bunch of pages full of generated boxes (I don't have any control over their generation), and each of the boxes gets a unique widget-ID. Of the hundreds of boxes on the dozens of pages, there are about 8 or 10 that I would really like to treat as a class. I need to apply uniform CSS to these, or to elements within them. The way I currently do it is along the lines of:

```
#widget-1511991600116, #widget-1512001156652, #widget-1512078219775, #widget-1512078668199, #widget-1512078835003, #widget-1512079211541, #widget-1512079388316 {
    format . . .
    . . . box
}
```

and

```
#widget-1511991600116 a, #widget-1512001156652 a, #widget-1512078219775 a, #widget-1512078668199 a, #widget-1512078835003 a, #widget-1512079211541 a, #widget-1512079388316 a {
    format links . . .
    . . . within box
}
```

etc.

There is no pattern to the numbers that are assigned, and there are existing boxes with numbers in between these, so I can't do an attribute selection based on the first part of the number or anything. I have to be able to specifically target these numbers.

**Is there any way I can lump all those together into a kind of on-the-fly class, and work with them that way?** Or do I just carry on with this ugliness?

Comment: There's probably an applicable way to target these elements while excluding the invalid elements in between them. Can you share a segment of the HTML that includes these? Like what are the valid and invalid elements? Having said that, in order to apply a class to each of these elements with something like JavaScript, you'd still need to 'target' each of the elements in question, so you couldn't really cut down on code.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Thanks. Maybe I wasn't clear. When I talked about "existing boxes with numbers in between these," I meant that the _numbers_ fall between these. So in other words, I can't just use `[id^="widget-1512"]` because there are lots of other boxes whose IDs would also meet that description.

Comment: I appreciate that, but maybe you could use a combination? Like say the 'invalid' ones start with `151`, but valid ones are both `15` and `1512`. You could style both of those, and then just set up a set of rules for the 'invalid' elements (`[id^="widget-151"])` that reset then back to their default with `inherit`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Yeah, no, that's not really possible. The numbers are all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

Given your current scenario. There doesn't seem to be a proper way to do it (I may be wrong). What I can suggest is that, if the boxes that you are targeting, appear at some specific location/position, and they won't change their location/position, then you can use `nth-child()` or `:nth-of-type()` to target them and apply your desired styles. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As these element IDs don't follow any meaningful pattern but are instead completely arbitrary selections, without any other knowledge of the nature of your markup or which pages these specific elements may or may not appear in, there is no way to shorten your selector-list in pure CSS.

When it comes to contextual selectors, even if Selectors 4's `:matches()` were widely available, it's not exactly going to reduce the byte count given that the rest of each contextual selector consists of nothing but a lone `a`.

If you're going to do this with a preprocessor you'll have to [build a fairly complex mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935102/build-list-of-selectors-with-less), at which point you might as well just do it the old-fashioned way.