# Can't define reusable comma separated selector lists in Less

Tags: less

Consider the following Less code:

```
.a {
  button,
  input[type='button'],
  input[type='submit'],
  input[type='reset'] {
    background: red;
  }
}

.b {
  button,
  input[type='button'],
  input[type='submit'],
  input[type='reset'] {
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do is define the four possible types of buttons in a reusable way. I used to be able to do this easily in SASS, but have switched to Less in order to use Semantic UI. I can't find a syntax to do this in Less - is it possible?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935102.

Comment: And for your particuar snippet above the solution is as easy as [this](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22button%2C%5Cninput%5Btype%3D'button'%5D%2C%5Cninput%5Btype%3D'submit'%5D%2C%5Cninput%5Btype%3D'reset'%5D%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20.a%20%26%20%7Bbackground%3A%20red%7D%5Cn%20%20%20.b%20%26%20%7Bbackground%3A%20blue%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have a solution to this now, derived from [this post](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1421):

```
@all-buttons: {
  button,
  input[type='button'],
  input[type='reset'],
  input[type='submit'] {
    .get-props()
  }
};

.set-props(@selectors; @rules; @extension: ~'') {
  @selectors();
  .get-props() {
     &@{extension} { @rules(); }
  }
}

.all-buttons(@rules; @extension: ~'') {
  .set-props(@all-buttons; @rules; @extension);
}

.a {
  .all-buttons({
    background: red;
  });
}

.b {
  .all-buttons({
    background: blue;
  });
}

// Also enables an extension such as a pseudo selector for each button type
.c {
  .all-buttons({
    background: green;
  }, ~':hover');
}
```